# Receive multiple value from php file via ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is my ajax call code. I want to send one data in .php file via ajax call and want to get two values from .php file. This two values I want to set in different 'input' tags whose id are 'course_name' and 'course_credit'.

Here my ajax call return correct value(real value from DB table) of 'course_name' input tag.
But 'MY PROBLEM IS' the value of input tag whose id is 'course_credit' shows 'success'. How can I get the correct value(real value from DB table) of id 'course_credit' ?

I have a 'select' tag which id is 'c_select'

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="course_name" id="course_name" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="course_credit" id="course_credit" value=""/>
```

AJAX :

```
$('#c_select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'get_course_info_db.php',
        data: 'c_id='+ $(this).val(),                 
        success: function(reply_data1,reply_data2){
            $('#course_name').val(reply_data1);
            $('#course_credit').val(reply_data2);
        }
    }); 
});
```

get_course_info_db.php

```
<?php 
       include('db_connection.php'); 
       $c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE c_id = '$c_id'"); 
       $all_course_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
       $c_name = $all_course_data['c_name'];
       $c_credit = $all_course_data['c_credit']; 
       echo $c_name,$c_credit;
       exit();  
 ?>
```

Comment: Look into JSON and get your PHP file to return a JSON object containing the two values, that's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AJAX code:-

```
$('#c_select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'get_course_info_db.php',
        data: 'c_id='+ $(this).val(),                 
        success: function(value){
            var data = value.split(",");
            $('#course_name').val(data[0]);
            $('#course_credit').val(data[1]);
        }
    }); 
  });
```

PHP code:-

```
<?php 
     include('db_connection.php'); 
     $c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE c_id = '$c_id'"); 
     $all_course_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $c_name = $all_course_data['c_name'];
     $c_credit = $all_course_data['c_credit']; 
     echo $c_name.",".$c_credit;
     exit();   
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The *success* callback is  **Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR );** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

php:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $c_name,
    'credit' => $c_credit,
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

javascript:

```
success: function(data) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#course_name').val(result.name);
    $('#course_credit').val(result.credit);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(reply_data1,reply_data2){
    $('#course_name').val(reply_data1);
    $('#course_credit').val(reply_data2);
}
```

second arguement is the status of http request, you have to encode the answer, i suggest you JSON
in your php

```
$c_credit = $all_course_data['c_credit']; 
echo json_encode(array('name' => $c_name,'credit' => $c_credit));
exit();
```

and in your javascript

```
 success: function(response,status){
     var datas = JSON.parse(response);
     $('#course_name').val(datas.name);
     $('#course_credit').val(data.credit);
 }
```

this is not tested, but this is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [JSON](http://json.org/) to encode the data you fetch from the database.

Try changing your ajax call as follows:

```
$('#c_select').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'get_course_info_db.php',
        data: 'c_id='+ $(this).val(),
        dataType: 'json', // jQuery will expect JSON and decode it for you
        success: function(reply_data){
            $('#course_name').val(reply_data['c_name']);
            $('#course_credit').val(reply_data['c_credit']);
        }
    }); 
});
```

And your PHP as follows:

```
include('db_connection.php'); 
// Escape your input to prevent SQL injection!
$c_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c_id']); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE c_id = '$c_id'"); 
$all_course_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($all_course_data);
exit();
```

I haven't tested this but I imagine it'd work for you.